How can I implement Chained Comparison Operator support for my Programming Language?
To begin with, my programming language, named Ignite, is a transpiled programming language and translates the Ignite Source File to a C++ source file.
Chained Comparison Operator is when you have comparison operators (such as <=, !=, >, etc.) that are chained together, meaning that multiple of these operators are used in a single expression without introducing other logical operators to separate them. One example would be: x < y < z.
The question is what black magic do I perform to interpret this expression as a valid expression in C++ IN a way that it aligns with Mathematics?
As of Python, it just simply adds an AND expression in between chained operators, so x < y < z would become x < y && y < z. It works good for simple cases as this one. My initial thought was to allow only one comparison operator at a time, so if you used < for first operator in the chain, you have to use only < in the proceeding ones in the chain. But this is not ideal because you can have this expression x < y <= z as a valid Mathematical expression.
Okay... then if I allow mixing operators, x < y > z is a valid operator chain but has no meaning in Mathematics (correct me if I am wrong). And this will be interpreted as x < y && y > z.
But what if you have expression as x != y != z? This is a valid Mathematical expression that says "x, y and z are not equal to each other". But interpreting it as x != y && y != z would not be best description, as x could still equal z.
What I have came up with is to interpret it as x != y && x != z && x != z, as comparing all the variables with all the others except itself. This works well when you have same type of operator. But quickly becomes problem for x < y <= z. Which of the two (< or <=) would you use to compare x with z when interpreting?
So I have gone ahead and use both of the two operators and OR them, so it would interpret it as x < y && (x < z || x <= z) && y <= z. But now what if you have a valid Mathematical expression x == y == z != 1 which means "x, y and z are all equal but not equal to 1". Using my logic would result in expression x == y && x == z && (x == 1 || x != 1) && y == z && (y == 1 || y != 1) && z != 1... Thinking about it, it works... but is there a better way of doing it?
Thanks.

I have no idea why you think this works in Python but not in C++. Every special case has the same problems in Python. Also I'd strongly object to x != y != z implying x != z. != is not transitive. You going lengths to do something with x < y <= z is a bit weird. < is transitive. Or am I missing something here? In any case, if things are really complex, write something that creates a structure of tokens (here, variables and comparators), a list of objects of some specific class, and then something that evaluates such a list.

I don't really see a question here. Or rather, you're already answering your own question: You do it by thinking about which operator "chains" you want to support and what they're supposed to mean, and compiling that to code that has the semantics you want. There's no magic trick to it, you need to put in the work, and it looks like you're already doing that. FWIW, I would not interpret x ≠ y ≠ z to mean x ≠ z even in mathematics, equality is transitive but inequality isn't.

What are the rules of "valid Mathematical expressions"? nterpreting it as x != y && y != z would not be best description, as x could still equal z. But x != y != z does not imply x != z. It is fine. Found exact your case on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequation : For example i ≠ 0 ≠ j is shorthand for  i ≠ 0 and 0 ≠ j, which does not imply  i ≠ j. I would interpret exactly v1 op1 v2 op2 v3 always as exactly v1 op1 v2 and v2 op2 v3 and nothing more.

Voting to close as "opinion based", as language design is formalizing opinions into language semantics. Not C++ either.

I would only allow chaining the same operator, and disallow chaining !=.

@KamilCuk Mathematics doesn't have a set in stone notation. x != y != z means whatever you want it to mean. You explain it in the foreword and move on. Ans that wilki article, and in particular the claim you are referencing, needs additional citations for verification. IOW isn't worth much in its current state.

It feels you should only allow chaining transitive relations, that is equivalence/equality and ordering operators (as long as ordering operators are in the same direction). a < b == c <= d makes it possible to deduce the properties of each number relative to all the other numbers (example, we know that a < d) whereas a < b != c >= d does not allow to make a similar deduction. You may need to require the order relations to be complete (e.g. what if, due to their type a < b makes sense, b = c too but a < c does not?).

Thank you for pointing out transitive relations. I will look into it and design my programming language using those principles. I think this is exactly what I was looking for.
@Botje , I don't think it is about opinion? Comparison (or relational operator) chaining is strongly defined in Mathematics I believe.
@n. m. could be an AI , doesn't x != y != z mean x, y and z are distinct from each other?

Forget about "Mathematics" for a minute; at the very least, to me, x != y != z isn't something I would read and immediately think: OK, I understand what that means (just the fact you have a different opinion than what the link from @KamilCuk shared is proof of that). IMHO, It is also something that should be rare for your users to write Now, the purpose of your language is to.... introduce equivocal syntaxes because C++ is just too easy? Is that it?

I may not be the only one to think x != y != z would imply x != z, but after reading the wiki about inequation I got to know it that it does not inherently mean x != z.
The purpose of my programming language is primarily to allow flexibility but I am also trying to keep it simple. I think I am failing on the second part...

So x,z < y would be evaluated as x < y && z < y? I guess it's time to ditch comma operator! (at least in the case of comparison operators I guess)

At the end of the day, it is up to you what syntax you want to implement (but I think x, z < y is the natural way this would be written in math expressions). Anyway, I was just saying there are alternatives to some of the expressions you put in your question. If x&z < y or [x z] < y look better to you, go for it. On top of that, the syntax supports any number of variables (a, b, c, d, e < y), which x < y > z does not.

Simplicity is a feature for a programmation language and I think supporting all the expressions from your question is a level of complexity you do not want.
As was demonstrated in comments, expression such as x != y != z does not make it obvious if x != z and the reason why it is not obvious is that!= is not a transitive relation.
What I would recommend to you is:

Only allow to chain operators a <op> b <op> c if it implies a <op> c.
The operators <op> do not need to be the same BTW, for instance, from a < b = c <= d, you can deduce something for all the pairs of variables:


For a: a < b, c, d

For b: a < b, b = c, b <= d

For c: a < c b = c, c <= d

For d: see above.
Just having transitive operators is not enough, they must not have conflicting directions (do not mix </<= with >/>=) and be applicable to all pairs of operands (e.g. what if, due to their type a < b makes sense, b = c too but a < c does not?).
For the reasoning, it should help if you search for an injective function / bijection f from your type to real numbers can be ordered; if you find one, you can write a < b iif f(a) < f(b).



For the case x < y > z where you mix operators you shouldn't, according to the above, there may be a smarter syntax to support the case.
The proposed syntax is x, z < y.

At the end of the day, you could allow some subtle expressions such as:

0 < a,b <= c meaning 0 < a && 0 < b && a <= c && b <= c
0 < a = b <= c, slightly different, meaning 0 < a && a == b && b <= c (note how a <= c is not tested)


You don't have to treat all chains of operators the same way.
If you really want to define x != y != z as x != y && x != z && x != y1, that doesn't stop you from defining x < y <= z as x < y && y <= z, and also defining x < y > z as a syntax error.
You will also want to define how many times the side effects of evaluating x, y, z occur. The sensible answer is once, because that means that any of the schemes you've discussed are actually equivalent (for the chains they allow)

You probably meant x != y && y != z && x != z

